# Convert double to int on Arm RVCT compiler in C language

Tags: c

I need to get last four bytes out of a double variable .The platform is Arm and compiler is RVCT.Programming language used is C.What is the safest way.

Thanks

Comment: Converting a double to an int and reinterpreting the last four bytes of a double as an int are two totally different tasks.  Which one do you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int lastFour = *(((char*) &origDouble) + sizeof(double) - 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double dval = 3.14159;

// as an int
uint32_t ival = *(uint32_t*)&dval;

// as bytes
uint8_t *all_bytes = (uint8_t*)&dval;

uint8_t *last_four_bytes = all_bytes + 4;
```